# What is the best way to delete object from complex JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I have a JavaScript object which looks like this:

```
{
    "filters": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 1207700620,
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1207825584,
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1207969166,
                    "checked": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Empty",
            "items": []
        },
        {
            "name": "ThirdList",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "1207828314",
                    "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "1236723086",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "1208005603",
                    "checked": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My `object` have a array by the name `filters`. This array contains multiple objects. Within each object there is an array by name `items`. For each element in this `items` array, I need to check the `checked` property & `if it is false, I need to delete that record (that item in items array)`.

**I need to ensure IE 8 compatability**.

I can use a for loop on filters array and within this for loop I can use another for loop to go over items array. I dont want this apporach.

Is there smarter way to achieve this by lodash or jquery or any other JavaScript library??

Comment: _"I can use a for loop on filters array and within this for loop I can use another for loop to go over items array. I dont want this apporach"_ - Why?

Comment: @Andreas: I just want to do with less code and smarter way. I always knew I can do with 2 for loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a combination of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods:

```
obj.filters.forEach(function(filter) {
    filter.items = filter.items.filter(function(el) {
        return el.checked;
    });
});
```

Check example below.

```js
var obj = {
    "filters": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 1207700620,
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1207825584,
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1207969166,
                    "checked": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Empty",
            "items": []
        },
        {
            "name": "ThirdList",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "1207828314",
                    "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "1236723086",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "1208005603",
                    "checked": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

obj.filters.forEach(function(filter) {
    filter.items = filter.items.filter(function(el) {
        return el.checked;
    });
});

alert( JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) );
```

For IE8 compatibility you can use polyfills or ES5 shims.

Another option if you can use Underscore/Lo-Dash, you can go with analog methods: `_.each` and `_.filter` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
_.each(obj.filters, function(filter) {
    filter.items = _.filter(filter.items, function(el) {
        return el.checked;
    });
});
```